# How to render a component conditionally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have shop.js component where Navbar and ProductList Components are render.I want when someone search then instead of ProductList Component ,searchShop component should render.

Shop Component

```
const Shop = () => {
    return (
        <div className='bb1'>
            <Navbar/>
            <ProductList/>
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Shop;
```

Navbar Component

```
const Navbar = () => {
 const [state,setState]=useState({
        searchText:'',
    })

   
//Some API CALL run only when user search something
return(

 state.searchText?<SearchShop/>:""

)}
```

Comment: Do the official React docs on [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) help answer your question regarding conditionally rendering a component? If not, then please [edit] the post to make it more clear what exactly you are trying to  accomplish and clarify what any issue(s) is/are you are facing, including a complete [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Add a function in shop.js where you need to set the visibility of product list and pass the function reference to navbar. So when search text is updated call the function.

```
    const Shop = () => {
        const [showProduct, setShowProduct] = useState(true);
        const change_product_display_handler = (state) =>{
            setShowProduct(state)
    }
    return (
        <div className='bb1'>
            <Navbar setProduct={change_product_display_handler}/>
            {showProduct &&<ProductList/>}
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Shop;
```

In navbar in function where you got values of search text add the following function

```
const Navbar = () => {
 const [state,setState]=useState({
        searchText:'',
    })
const on_search_handler = () =>{
var searchvalue = //get value here;
//update setstate
 if (searchvalue === '') {
        props.setProduct(true);
    } else {
props.setProduct(false);
}
return(  );
};

export default Navbar ;
```

Answer (score 0):

But you need to clarify if you need component inside the Navbar, or instead of the `ProductList` component. If you want the `ProductList` to be replaced, you need to propagate the API call via some kind of state management, and have your logic in the Shop function:

```
const Shop = () => {
searchText = getStateFunction(state => state.searchText)

return (
    <div className='bb1'>
        <Navbar/>
      {searchText ? <ProductList/> : <SearchShop/>}
        <Footer/>
    </div>
   );
};

export default Shop;
```

There are many options for global state, I suggest you go look through the different options, but my absolute favorite to recommend, is Zustand. It's very easy to both setup, and use.

According to [the React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) you can do conditional rendering in several ways. Inline, etc., make sure you are using the the method you are most familiar or comfortable with.